# Anyone Know How to Calculate the Area/Perimeter/Height of a Triangle?

Tags: python, height, area

I'm a newbie to Python and I came across this question somewhere:

"Produce a programme that can calculate the perimeter of the triangle, the area of the triangle and the height of the triangle from the length of the three sides of a triangle. If the three lengths of the sides of the triangle do not define a valid triangle, a message should be displayed stating that this is not a valid calculation and the process should be terminated."

Anyone know how this could be solved? It's probably easy, but I'm a newbie so yeah

This is what I've got so far:

```
a = float(input('Please Enter the First side of a Triangle: '))

b = float(input('Please Enter the Second side of a Triangle: '))

c = float(input('Please Enter the Third side of a Triangle: '))

if  a + b >= c and b + c >= a and c + a >= b:

# calculate area and height here


Perimeter = a + b + c

s = (a + b + c) / 2

Area = (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) ** 0.5

print("\n The Perimeter of Triangle = %.2f" %Perimeter);

print(" The Area of a Traiangle is %0.2f" %Area)     
else:
print('Not a valid triangle')
```

I still have to calculate the height. Everything else seems to be working now :D

Comment: Post the code sample that you tried , so that it will be easy for people to answer.

Comment: Remove the `a, b, c = 1, 1, 1` line and move your three `input()` lines before the if statement to make it work.

Comment: You can get the height with sin, cos or tan... In python you can access these through the math package... (`import math`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In mathematics, the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) states that for any triangle, the sum of the lengths of any two sides must be greater than or equal to the length of the remaining side.

```
a, b, c = 1, 1, 1 # sides of a triangle
if a + b >= c and b + c >= a and c + a >= b:
    # calculate area and height here
else:
    print('Not a valid triangle')
```

Comment: Thanks, check what I added to my original post

Comment: Is there no easier way to go about calculating the height?

Comment: Not that I know of, maybe you can find a library for that but I really doubt it, the functions are all there if you know how to calculate it in a calculator. Here a list of all math functions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html